# Cannot run server in virtualenv on Gitbash "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, git-bash

I am trying to run the django server locally on my gitbash. I started with the following command lines:

```
virtualenv env

pip install -r requirements.txt

pip install django

django-admin --version
3.0.7

pip --version
19.2.3

python --version
2.7.6
```

Variable PATH: `C:\Users\circulating\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\;C:\Users\circulating\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin\;C:\Python27;C:\Users\circulating\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\circulating\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Users\circulating\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\heroku\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem`

Error

```
$ python manage.py runserver 0:8000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 13, in main
    "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

Based off the error I need to:

- install Django(which is since i checked the version)
- Add to PYTHONPATH environment variable(not sure if or how to do this)
- Activate a virtual environment(activated in beginning)

I am not sure if the problem is with my gitbash running on python2.7 as oppose to 3.7. The Django docs say Django(3.0)  -> Python(3.6, 3.7, 3.8). However, I have both python 2.7 and 3.7 installed and in my PATH variable

Comment: "*activated in beginning*" It was not activated. You've created a virtual env but didn't activate it. After `virtualenv env` you need to do `. env/bin/activate`. "*Add to PYTHONPATH*" With an activated virtual env you don't need to modify `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: source ./env_name/bin/activate gives me 
(bash: ./env_name/bin/activate: No such file or directory)

Comment: Ow, git-bash! The directory `bin` in w32 is called `Scripts`, damn it! `. env/Scripts/activate`. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-bash%5D+%5Bvirtualenv%5D+activate

Comment: thank you! that helped.